# Clock program using coordinates and time_t

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to create c++ program that simulates a clock. It is supposed to display the date/time and constantly update. I found a way to make it all work perfectly, but I want to understand the code. I am very new to programming and ideally would like to have an understanding of every line.

I understand that THIS line of code sets up the foundation to move the cursor back to a specified point on the screen-- in my program it's used to go back to the 'beginning' and 'overlap' what was previously displayed.

```
void gotoxy (int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord; // coordinates
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y; // X and Y coordinates
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

Could someone please explain the coordinates to me? I do not understand the reasoning behind what is in the braces.

Within main() I have this code:

```
time_t now;
    while (true)
    {
        gotoxy (0,0);
        now = time(0);
        cout << "The time is now: " << ctime(&now);
        Sleep (20);
    }
    cin.get ();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

I thought that `time_t` is a function of C/C++ that shows the elapsed time since Jan 1, 1970. I do not understand how this outputs my current time.

I have tried to comment out bits of the code to see what goes wrong in an attempt to figure out how this whole thing works, but no luck there. I have also searched hours on the internet, going line by line, to see if i could get some insight on this. I have come to my last resort and am simply asking anyone to help me understand what is going on in this code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`I thought that time_t is a function of C/C++ that shows the elapsed time since Jan 1, 1970.`

`time_t` is a not a function, it is `arithmetic type capable of representing times`.
see here for more information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t,

```
now = time(0);
```

Returns the current calendar time encoded as a std::time_t object. see here for more information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time, time(0) means the time `now`.

```
ctime(&now); //transform time now in human readable format
```

Convert `time_t` value to string
Interprets the value pointed by timer as a calendar time and converts it to a C-string containing a human-readable version of the corresponding time and date, in terms of local time.
The returned string has the following format:

```
Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy
```

here has more information about ctime: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates are just the character position in the terminal. `(0,0)` probably means go back to the first character. When doing that, the output will overwrite the characters in the console, giving the illusion it 'updates' the time.

As for the time function, you can read the document of [ctime here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/?kw=ctime). It return a human readable format of the date, not a counter.

Which part of the code is not clear exactly?

It is a simple infinite loop (`cin.get ();` will never be reached and the program will never return btw). Inside the loop, the cursor goes back to the beginning of the line, print the time and waits 20 seconds to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

To tell [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) what is targeted (x, y) you have to use [`COORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Defines the coordinates of a character cell in a console screen
>   buffer. The origin of the coordinate system (0,0) is at the top, left
>   cell of the buffer.

To retrieve the time, you can use type [`time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) and function [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time):

> `time_t` - this is almost always a integral value holding the number of
>   seconds since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC